# Store custom log in database yii2

Tags: logging, yii, yii2

I am trying to store details like `requestedRoute`, `controller name` ,`action name` `logged in user id` in my log table.
so I extended  `yii\log\DbTarget`.

```
namespace api\components;

use Yii;
use yii\log\DbTarget;

class DbExpTarget extends DbTarget{
    public function export(){
        $tableName = $this->db->quoteTableName($this->logTable);

        $sql = "INSERT INTO $tableName ([[event]], [[controller]], [[action]], [[userId]], [[createdAt]])
            VALUES (:event, :controller, :action,:userId, :createdAt)";

        $command = $this->db->createCommand($sql);

        $event=Yii::$app->controller->controllerule->requestedRoute;

        $controller=Yii::$app->controller->uniqueId;

        $action=Yii::$app->controller->action->id;

        $user=Yii::$app->user->identity->id;

        $command->bindValues([
            ':event' => $event,
            ':controller' => $controller,
            ':action' => $action,        
            ':userId' => $user,
            ':createdAt' => time(),
        ])->execute();
    }
}
```

**config/main.php**

```
'log' => [
    'traceLevel' => YII_DEBUG ? 3 : 0,
    'targets' => [
        [
            'class' => 'api\components\DbExpTarget',
            'levels' => ['info','trace','error']
        ]
    ]
]
```

but in `export()` function I am unable to access current action (`$action=Yii::$app->controller->action->id`) and logged in user id(`Yii::$app->user->identity->id`) 
How can I get that details? or any easy method to log these details?

Comment: `Yii::$app` is static so it is available everywhere after bootstrap process. As long as the properties you are looking for are set you can read them. For example `Yii::$app->user->identity->id` is not set for guests.

Comment: I checked it after login as a user but it is not working, even I am not able to access the `action id`

Comment: But you do have `use Yii;` in this class header?

Comment: @Bizley Yes I have

Comment: I see now this is API class. You need to debug it and see what is available there. Check content of `Yii::$app->user` and others, remember that log can run even before the controller is invoked.

Comment: can you suggest any better method for logging this details.

Comment: Well, when it's available you can still log them, just check first if `Yii::$app->controller` and `Yii::$app->user->identity` is not empty.

Comment: user identity and action are not available,but the controller is not empty